# Retrieve the return type by the function reference?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Hi suppose I have a type typedef ReturnType  (ObjectType::*fun1 )( Arg0 ); is it possible somehow to get the return type and number of the arguments by having one reference to the function?

For instance now I have:

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ReturnType, typename Arg0, typename Arg1  >
Private::value_fun< ObjectType, TYPELIST_2(Arg0, Arg1), ReturnType > val_mem_funcion(typename Private::value_fun<ObjectType, TYPELIST_2(Arg0, Arg1), ReturnType>::FunctionType func, Arg0 arg0, Arg1 arg1) {
    return Private::value_fun <ObjectType, TYPELIST_2(Arg0, Arg1), ReturnType>( func, arg0, arg1 );
}
```

and my call is:

```
std::for_each( test.begin(), test.end(), utils::val_mem_funcion<Test, int>(&Test::sum, 33, 44)  );
```

but it would be much better if I could remove the template arguments and make it like:

```
std::for_each( test.begin(), test.end(), utils::val_mem_funcion(&Test::sum, 33, 44)  );
```

Comment: What error is outputted by the compiler when you try it ?

Comment: @Synxis error: no matching function for call to ‘val_mem_funcion(int (Test::*)(int, int), int, int)’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the function `T f();`, the return type can be extracted like this (requires `C++11`):

```
typedef decltype(f()) ReturnType;
```

Now `ReturnType` equals to type `T` above.

Comment: I meant by having the f can you somehow retreive the the void?

something like:
typedef getReturnType<f>::Result ReturnType;

Comment: `typedef decltype(f()) ReturnType;`

Comment: Yah that works, but I need a c++11 then xmm. You can modify your answer and I will accept it as a correct one then. Thank you!!!